# Scripting to Backup DB in tar.gz

Tags: scripts, mysql, backup, tar

I wrote the following script to backup my server:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
THESITE="sitename.ir"
THEDB="mydb"
THEDBPW="mypassword"
THEDATE=`date +%d%m%y%H%M`

mysqldump -u $THEDBUSER -p${THEDBPW} $THEDB | gzip > /media/bkfolder/dbbackup_${THEDB}_${THEDATE}.bak.gz

tar -cpzf /var/backups/sitebackup_${THESITE}_${THEDATE}.tar.gz  /var/www

# Print end status message.
echo "Backup finished"
```

But I receive this error:

> tar: Remove leading / from member names

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error; it is a notice. tar archives have relative paths so this is correct behaviour: when you "untar" the file you provide the command with a place it should extract and in case of absolute paths it will install it into the root directory regardless of what you told it should use as a path. Makes the untarring illogical.

See `man tar` and the P option if you want absolute paths (but please do not).

```
 -P, --absolute-names
       don't strip leading '/'s from file names
```